# Cygwin version (in)compatibility

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to run a program (http://dar.linux.free.fr/) that I built myself using Cygwin for Windows/32. I'm now trying to run it using a more recent (not by much, just a few months) version of Cygwin. Instead of running, it spits out:

> 2 [main] dar (xxxx) shared_info::initialize: size of shared memory region changed from 37742 to 38776

I presume this is due to attempting to run using incompatible dynamic libraries. A curious thing is that if I run it from a regular (ie non-Cygwin) then it runs fine. It also runs if I type

> cmd /S dar

although in the latter case I get some warnings about there being no terminal and hence no user interaction.

OK so maybe I should just rebuild it using the current version of Cygwin. But this is a slow and painful process, and not one I'd like to have to go through every time I upgrade Cygwin. And the fact that the code runs fine outside the Cygwin environment gives me hope that I can make it work.

I tried changing the PATH in the Cygwin environment to force it to pick up all the Cygwin dynamic libraries that were bundled with the dar executable (ie the same ones that are used when running outside Cygwin). But I had no luck there.

Can anyone suggest a simple solution or work-around?

Many thanks!

Comment: how you built it? With which compiler ?

Comment: I don't have the build environment any more but the version information on the running executable reports being compiled with GNUC version 7.4.0